# About python coding relate to Tartans

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This link is the [Project requirements](https://rahollis.github.io/Projects/tartans/tartans.html) I'm doing pattern 28

That's my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
color_dictionary = {'K' : [16/255, 16/255, 16/255], 'R' : [200/255, 0, 0], 'Y' : [216/255, 176/255, 0]}
color_code = [('K',16), ('Y',4) ,('K',32) ,('Y',48) ,('R',4) ,('Y',48) ,('K',32),('Y',4), ('K',16)]
 def show_tartan(n):
    plt.figure(figsize=[10,10])
    a=0
    colorstripev=np.zeros((n,n,3))
    while a<=n: 
        for i,j in color_code:
            #print(color_dictionary[i])
            colorstripev[:,a:a+j,:]=color_dictionary[i]
            a=a+j
    colorstripeh=np.transpose(colorstripev, (1, 0, 2))
    stripe=colorstripev+colorstripeh
    plt.imshow(stripe)
    plt.show()
print(show_tartan(500))
```

I'm confused about "A more realistic image of a tartan can be obtained by modifying the way in which vertical and horizontal stripes are combined. Instead of using the checkerboard pattern, each column of pixels shows two pixels of vertical stripes, then two pixels of horizontal stripes, and so on. In each subsequent column, this pattern gets shifted down by one pixel:"

I'm not sure how to do it. That's what I got
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H69cp.png)

Comment: They're saying instead of column 1 "H V H V" and column 2 "V H V H", use column 1 "H H V V", then column 2 "V H H V", then column 3 "V V H H", then column 4 "H V V H" and repeat.

Comment: i think i understand it, but i still don't know how to write the code